# Problem using "slash character" / key-shortcut 

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, special-characters

A few hours ago, the only shortcut for the "slash character" <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> stopped working in my Ubuntu environment. I know it is not a physical error, because it is still working on my" root user".

What can I do about it?

Comment: What keyboard layout is that?  I've never seen one that didn't have `/` on a normal key?

Comment: Brasil - PC (Inrl) Generic 105 keys.

Comment: Is this a problem just in a terminal, or everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

The gui approach: `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard`, there you can check the second tab. This settings are per user.

You can check the working settings of the **user root** by doing the following in a terminal
`sudo -u root gnome-keyboard-properties`

You can open both dialoges at the sametime to get a side by side comparison.

Comment: I did. And both have the same configuration. :(

Comment: @FRD Please update your question with the things you have tried so that people who run into this have as much information right away.